# ERROR TypeError: can't assign to property "validator" on "12345": not an object

Tags: html, angular, typeerror

I want to build a pre filled form, as of now I am getting this error when i try to display the form page. I have tried various solutions that was given but that doesn't seem to work here.

My hardwareRequest.ts

```
hardwareReviewForm: FormGroup;
  assetSerialNumber = new FormControl('');
  modelType = new FormControl('');



ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = []
    this.service.loadRequestData(this.requestId).subscribe(
      (response: any) => {
        
        this.data = response
        console.log(this.data)
        this.assetSerialNumber = this.data.assetSerialNumber
        this.modelType = this.data.modelType

      },
      (error) => {

       
      }
    )
  }
```

My HTML file

```
<form class="example-container" [formGroup]="hardwareReviewForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
                
              <div class="ds-col-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="ds-col-6">
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                      <mat-label>Asset Serial Number: </mat-label>
                      <input formControlName="assetSerialNumber" readonly matInput type="text">
                  </mat-form-field>
              </div>

              <div class="ds-col-6">
                  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                      <mat-label>Part No./Model Type: </mat-label>                
                          <input formControlName="modelType" readonly matInput type="text">                     
                  </mat-form-field>
              </div>
              </div>

            </form>
```

Comment: when i use [formControl] I get the error, but when i use formControlName no data gets displayed in the inputs

Comment: Please show errors and all text-based information as text in the question, rather than as a picture of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a 'View Model' of your fields and then reset your form with it.

```
  export class testVm {
        assetSerialNumber : number;
        modelType : string;
    }
  var model: testVm = this.data;
  this.hardwareReviewForm.reset(model)
```

Or if you want to assign value separately you should act like this:

```
this.hardwareReviewForm.controls["assetSerialNumber"].reset(this.data.assetSerialNumber.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to define form controls inside formGroup;

```
hardwareReviewForm = new FormGroup({
  assetSerialNumber = new FormControl('');
  modelType = new FormControl('');
});
```

Secondly, you set the values to controls like below;

```
this.hardwareReviewForm.get('assetSerialNumber').setValue(this.data.assetSerialNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.. It was a silly mistake of .setValue for form controls.
setting my value like below works fine.

this.Number.setValue(this.data.Number)
this.Type.setValue(this.data.Type)